# displaying --stats from rsync command

Tags: applescript

I use the following code to copy whole folders:

```
set source_folder to POSIX path of (choose folder)
set target_folder to POSIX path of (choose folder)

try
    do shell script "rsync -rlpta --stats " & source_folder & " " & target_folder)
on error
    display alert "This script uses rsync and does not work if there are spaces in the folder names!"
end try
```

Is there any way to catch the returned statistics "--stats" for display or as text e.g. logging.

Comment: set myResult to result "I really should read manuals duh!"

Comment: The script works with spaces in folder names when you write `set source_folder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the do shell script command to a variable to capture the value returned from the command. Also, you should always use "quoted form of x" when passing a variable to do shell script.

```
set source_folder to POSIX path of (choose folder)
set target_folder to POSIX path of (choose folder)

try
    set statResult to do shell script "rsync -rlpta --stats " & quoted form of source_folder & " " & quoted form of target_folder
    return statResult
on error err
    display alert err
end try
```